# avro php - reading from buffer

Tags: php, avro

I am writing a php script using avro to deserialize data.
I receive the data as a buffer of avro binary stream.
In the avro php example, I see only an example of reading the data from a file. not a binary buffer.

How can I deserialize the data?
What I am looking for is a binary decoder for avro

Answer (score 0):

```
$binaryBuffer = <get_avro_serialized_record>

$writersSchema = '{
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "Example",
    "namespace" : "com.example.record",
    "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "userId",
    "type" : "int"
    .............
}'

$reader = new AvroIODatumReader($writersSchema);
$io = new AvroStringIO($binaryBuffer)
$deserializedRecord = $reader->read(new AvroIOBinaryDecoder($io))
```

assuming you want to deserialize each record separately, and have the writers schema.