# Encode/Decode avro records in PHP

Tags: php, avro

Are there any libraries to encode/decode avro records in PHP? I'm specifically looking to decode kafka records (that are produced via PHP RDKafka)

Comment: i knew this is a 3 years+ post. Did you manage to to solve this and how? tq

Answer (score 0):

you can check out my answer for how to use https://github.com/researchgate/avro-php:

[avro php - reading from buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765190/avro-php-reading-from-buffer)